# Error: get_distance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'point'

Tags: parameters, self, positional-parameter

Getting Error: get_distance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'point' when  the function is already defined with one positional argument called point.

Here is the class:

```
    from math import radians, sin, cos, acos, atan2, sqrt

class GeoPoint:
    lat = ''
    lon = ''

    # Initialize
    def __init__(self, lat=0, lon=0, des='TBD') -> None:
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.description = des

    def set_point(self, point):
        self.lat = point[0]
        self.lon = point[1]

    def get_point(self):
        return (self.lon, self.lat)

    # Properties
    point = property(get_point, set_point)

    def get_distance(self, point): 
        lat1 = radians(self.lat)
        lon1 = radians(self.lon)
        lat2 = radians(point.lat)
        lon2 = radians(point.lon)
        print("\nInput coordinates of two points:")
        lat1 = radians(float(input("Starting latitude: ")))
        lon1 = radians(float(input("Ending longitude: ")))
        lat2 = radians(float(input("Second Starting latitude: ")))
        lon2 = radians(float(input("Second Ending longitude: ")))

        # Problem solving distance
        dist = 6371.01 * acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1 - lon2))
        print("The distance is %.2fkm." % dist)

    def get_description(self):
        return (self.description)

    def set_description(self,description):
        self.description = description
```

Here is the script:

```
from GeoPoint import GeoPoint

def doanother():
    '''Asks user if they want to do another and returns True or False'''
    usr_response = input("Do another (y/n)? ")
    another = usr_response.strip()[0].lower() == 'y'
    return another

while True:
    try:
        dist = ()
        geo = GeoPoint
        point1 = GeoPoint(12.3456, -123.4567, 'Loc1')
        point2 = GeoPoint()
        point2.point = 23.4567, -213.456
        point2.description = 'Loc2'

        # get user coordinates
        choice = (input('Enter the lat and lon of your location: '))
        latlon = tuple(map(float, choice.split(', ')))
        print("latlon:",latlon)
        print('latlon[0]:',latlon[0])
        print('latlon[1]:',latlon[1])

        Loc = (input('Enter location: '))

        #Get distance to point 1
        point3 = GeoPoint(latlon[0], latlon[1], Loc)
        # point3 = GeoPoint()
        # point3.point = latlon
        dist[1] = geo.get_distance(point3)

        #Get distance to point 1
        point3 = GeoPoint(latlon, Loc)
        dist[2] = geo.get_distance(point3)
        distance = min(dist)

        # show result
        print(f'The shortest distance is: {min(dist)} ')  
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')

    if not doanother(): break
```

This is totally mystifying.  I checked to make sure that I instantiated the class before using it.  I don't know why Python think's that get_distance(self, point) takes an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Code segment was fraught with errors.  Once it was rewritten to eliminate the errors, the missing positional parameter error disappeared.